# Entry value converter hangs converting and converting back again and again

Tags: binding, xamarin.forms, ivalueconverter, valueconverter

I have an `Entry` which holds the **Price** and I wanted to format it as currency.
Here is the `Entry` tag

```
<Entry x:Name="Price" StyleId="Price"  
       Text="{Binding Model.Price, Converter={StaticResource CurrencyEntryFormatConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
       Placeholder="{x:Static resx:Resources.PricePlaceholder}"
       Style="{StaticResource DefaultEntry}" Keyboard="Numeric"/>
```

and here is the property in the `Model`

```
public decimal Price
{
    get
    {
        return this.price;
    }

    set
    {
        if (this.price== value)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.price= value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Finally here is the converter:

```
public class CurrencyEntryFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString()))
        {
            return value;
        }

        string result = string.Format(Resources.CurrencyFormatString, (decimal)value);
        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString()))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        string result = value.ToString().Replace(" ", "").Replace("$", "").Replace(",", "");
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Question:** My problem is that when I run the project and try to enter values in the Price field, the code repeats executing between **Convert** and **ConvertBack** functions of the converter and application hangs!
Any advice?

Comment: I had this problem a while ago too, though it was a number rounding issue. Generally, you'll need to break the chain somehow. I see that in ConvertBack you aren't converting the string to a decimal. Can you check to see if that helps? When the `if (this.price == value)` line is hit, what are the numbers, and do they evaluate to true at any time?

Comment: Yes @joe that was the error, and I already found it... It was a bit complicated because we had some renderers and in those renderers we were setting the value again, so it was becoming an infinit loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the problem was the property implementation
If we define a property of a class which is implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`, in order to update the view when the property value changes, we need to call `OnPropertyChanged` method in the `set` block:

```
public decimal Amount
{
    get
    {
        return this.amount;
    }

    set
    {
        this.amount = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged();  // like this line
    }
}
```

But just this code like so makes a loop with your bindings. So we need to be checking if the value is different than the current property's value and then if its new, update it. Look at this code:

```
public decimal Amount
{
    get
    {
        return this.amount;
    }

    set
    {
        if (this.amount == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.amount = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

That **if** block helps you to stop looping between **get** and **set**.
I hope it helps someone.