# Xamarin.Forms: How come the process of IValueConverter doesn't play ping pong for ever?

Tags: xamarin.forms, binding, converters

In Xamarin.Forms I implemented the interface IValueConverter.

```
public class NiceConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string valueAsString = value as string;
                
            return valueAsString + "SP";
         }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string valueAsString = value as string;

            return valueAsString + "GP";            
        }
    }
```

In the XML part I bind an Entry text, and specify I use that convertor:

```
<ContentPage.Resources> 
  <convertorsNS:NiceConverter x:Key="myAddDollarSignConverter"/>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<StackLayout>
  <Entry x:Name="myTextEntry" Text="{Binding NiceString ,
      Converter = {StaticResource NiceConverter }, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

I would expect that when ever I type one character in the entry, lets say 'A',
ConvertBack() would be called, so the string 'AGP' would be
sent to the source binded property,

but now this causes  to a change in the **Source**
binded property, so Convert () would be called, so the
string 'AGPSP' would be sent to the Target,

but now this causes to a change in the **Target**,
so now ConvertBack() would be called again, so the string AGPSPGP would be sent to the source

but now this causes  to a change in the **Source**...

...and this way I expect it to go on and on endlessly.

Of course I'm wrong. Can you please tell me where?

Comment: Where is the `NiceString` property defined? I'm guessing something is going on with the setter or the property changed call.

Comment: @Andrew Hi, NiceString is defined in a viewModel which is the Binding Context. The viewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and NiceString is ok. The problem is that a change in the text of the entry causes ConvertBack() to be called, which changes NiceString - This causes Convert() to be called, so it changes the entry Text and....that's it. it stops.

Answer (score 0):

> this way I expect it to go on and on endlessly.

1. The text would not display  as expected , it will cause infinite loop , the application hangs at that time .
2. It seems that Xamarin Team has fixed the problem that infinite loop would happen if we use converter on Entry when create binding .

Check the following threads ,the issue did exist before .

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/92310/two-way-binding-with-a-converter-causing-an-infinite-loop

[Entry value converter hangs converting and converting back again and again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36850348/entry-value-converter-hangs-converting-and-converting-back-again-and-again)

[Xamarin forms value converter causing infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43188865/xamarin-forms-value-converter-causing-infinite-loop)

Comment: Hi, I've read all the 3 links. All these links describe the wanted situation :-) This what I expect - an infinite loop. Of some reason, I don't get an infinite loop.  A change in the text of the entry causes ConvertBack() to be called, which changes NiceString - This causes Convert() to be called, so it changes the entry Text and....that's it. it stops. Now, It is possible that as you wrote "It seems that Xamarin Team has fixed the problem", but I don't know anything about such a fix. Did you see some documentation about it?

Comment: No documentation  about the fix ,  same code cause the issue before but now  infinite loop would never happen , you could raise issue on github for more details : https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues.